# How to perform any transformation(like log transformation, box-cox) in dataset, when dataset contains 0 and negative values in columns?

Tags: python, scipy

```
###  box-cox method

from scipy import stats

stats.boxcox(datamart[column])

ValueError: Data must be positive
```

I cannot perform log transformation too because it contains 0 values. I cannot remove 0 value rows.

Answer (score 0):

A common approach to log transforming data that contains zeroes is to simply use log(x+1). So in python you would do something like this:

```
x_transform = np.log(x+1)
```

Comment: What about negative values?

Comment: It is completely up to you... maybe log transformation isn't the best for your use case. But you could do log(x+(max_negative_value))